# Avoid stretching in three js

Tags: three.js

I'm wrapping a 3D model with texture in three js. But in some areas the image is stretching even though my texture is in good resolution.

[image]

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not related to programming. Try over on [Game Development SE](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Does this happen in your 3D modeling software too ? If yes, you need to work on UV stretching / unwrapping, and try and preserve the ratio making small UV islands.

Comment: @Hesha thank you. As you told its UV mapping issue.

Answer (score 2):

this is a UV mapping issue, not a THREE.js issue. check over in 3d modelling or game dev.